# Attribution in Firebase Analytics BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

In Google Analytics (GA4) GUI, under the traffic acquisition report, it is possible to see app visits split by source.

However, I cannot see the same info in BigQuery.

According to [GA4] BigQuery Export schema [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en) `traffic_source` is the "Name of the traffic source that first acquired the user". I have checked and in fact it seems that the value of `traffic_source` changes only when the  `user_pseudo_id` changes, which means it persists until the app is reinstalled.

**Scenario:**
User A installed the app with a google-play campaign, then visits the app a second time following a Google cpc campaign and then a third time following a push notification.

**Question:**
In BigQuery, how can I see that the second visit was from cpc and the third from the push notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `traffic_source` is indeed persisting over multiple sessions and it captures only the source of the first app install.

To get attribution at visit level, you need to use the parameters inside the `firebase_campaign` event, for example:

```
SELECT  
user_id,
user_pseudo_id,
event_date,
event_timestamp,
event_name,
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'source') AS source_,
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'medium') AS medium_
FROM `project.table.events_*` 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210316' AND '20210319'
AND event_name IN('firebase_campaign') 
AND user_id = 'XXXXX'
```